Mysql update not work, Update lochave SET LCNT = 11 WHERE LSC = 'E' and (LOCN1 >= 142 and LOCN2 <= 142);
I need to update lcnt depending on vars for locn1 to locn2
This below does not work
MariaDB [booksgood]> Update lochave SET LCNT = 11 WHERE LSC = 'E' and (LOCN1 >= 142 and LOCN2 <= 142);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.011 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

I was thinking it should set lcnt to 11 at this row
| 1961 | E    |   22 | 141.000000 | 143.000000 |

How can I write the update to do what I want?
MariaDB [booksgood]>  select id, lsc, lcnt, locn1, locn2 from lochave where lsc = 'E';

    +------+------+------+------------+------------+
    | id   | lsc  | lcnt | locn1      | locn2      |
    +------+------+------+------------+------------+
    | 1949 | E    |   22 |  11.000000 | 143.000000 |
    | 1950 | E    |   22 |  11.000000 |  29.000000 |
    | 1951 | E    |   22 |  29.000000 |  29.000000 |
    | 1952 | E    |   22 |  31.000000 |  49.200000 |
    | 1953 | E    |   22 |  51.000000 |  73.000000 |
    | 1954 | E    |   22 |  75.000000 |  99.000000 |
    | 1955 | E    |   22 |  81.000000 |  83.000000 |
    | 1956 | E    |   22 |  99.000000 |  99.000000 |
    | 1957 | E    |   22 | 101.000000 | 135.000000 |
    | 1958 | E    |   22 | 103.000000 | 110.000000 |
    | 1959 | E    |   22 | 111.000000 | 120.000000 |
    | 1960 | E    |   22 | 121.000000 | 135.000000 |
    | 1961 | E    |   22 | 141.000000 | 143.000000 |
    | 1962 | E    |    0 | 151.000000 | 889.000000 |
    | 1963 | E    |   22 | 151.000000 | 169.120000 |
    | 1964 | E    |   22 | 171.000000 | 183.900000 |
    | 1965 | E    |   22 | 171.000000 | 180.000000 |
    | 1966 | E    |   22 | 173.000000 | 173.000000 |
    | 1967 | E    |   22 | 175.000000 | 175.700000 |


It's correct.  From the data you provided, it should not return any result.

There is no row with LCON1 >= 142 and LCON2 <= 142

The query specifies lcon1 >= 142 while the row in question has a value of 141, which is certainly not greater or equal to 142. Similarly, you have condition lcon2 <= 142 while value in the table is 143.
It seems like you mean to have the operators the other way around:
Update lochave SET LCNT = 11 WHERE LSC = 'E' and (LOCN1 <= 142 and LOCN2 >= 142)


That worked, thank you.

I can't mark it solved as I need rep of 15 to cast vote. My brain was reversed!

Yes, working good, doing what I wanted to do, very happy.

@ScottDowney You don't need any reputation to mark an answer accepted, i.e. solved, only to upvote an answer. See What should I do when someone answers my question?.
